# How to take more than one qualifying record

Tags: c#, linq

```
var sortedAddr = listAddr.OrderBy(x => x.Address.Length);

var longestAddr = sortedAddr.Last();  
var shortedAddr = sortedAddr.First();
```

Now if the `longestaddr` contains more than one records with the same length, the above piece of code prints only one. However how to print multiple longest address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably start with the following code.

```
var minLength = listAddr.Min(y => y.Address.Length);
var maxLength = listAddr.Max(y => y.Address.Length);

var shortestAddr = listAddr.Where(x => x.Address.Length == minLength);
var longestAddr = listAddr.Where(x => x.Address.Length == maxLength);
```

It contains only a single optimization - pre-calculating the minimum and maximum length keeping the runtime linear instead of becoming quadratic.

Pre-sorting the list takes at least `O(n log(n))` and you only access it a few times after this expensive operation. You can of course do it and use `Where()` or `TakeWhile()` to get the desired addresses but this will make the code harder to read and probably even slower.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the length of the longest address and use [TakeWhile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804.aspx)

```
var sortedDesc = listAddr.OrderByDescending(x => x.Address.Length);
int longestAddress = sortedDesc.First().Address.Length;

var longest = sortedDesc.TakeWhile(x => x.Address.Length == longestAddress);
```

Alternatively you could group by address length and then get the 'largest' group:

```
var longest = listAddr.GroupBy(x => x.Address.Length)
    .Max(grp => grp.Key);
```

EDIT: To print them out you can just loop through the collection of largest addresses:

```
foreach(var address in longest.Select(x => x.Address))
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Address: {0}, length: {1}", address, address.Length);
}
```

Comment: thanks lee..anyway to print the length of address as well as address at the same time in shortest possible code?